# Athena Performance Testing

Tags: amazon-athena

Performing queries on csv data. (To test athena performance)
Query: select * from csvdata limit 10;
Here i'm testing how much data is scanned and the amount of time taken. When i ran same query again and again the time difference and data scanned is so volatile. Couldn't figure out what is the best time athena is taking to scan the data. Is it network latency? or anything wrong in my approach?
Looking forward to test joins, groupby, partitions and bucketing later. is there any usecase i can refer?

Answer (score 2):

Athena is a multi-tenant distributed system and you will see a lot of differences in query times depending on the time of day, the account you run the queries in, the region, and so on. Some queries might get queued, and the size of the result set also has an impact on the total query duration.

I suggest that you benchmark the exact same queries at different times of day, and make sure you always run against the same data. Measure the duration on the client, and also record the submission time, completion time, and engine execution time values from the `GetQueryExecution` API call. When you run a query in the Athena console it will report the engine execution time, but that does not include queueing and the time it takes to read the results in your client (the `GetQueryResults` can be very slow for large result sets).

Also record the amount of scanned data, that's an important number to look at when you are benchmarking partitioning and bucketing, as it can tell you if the query is making use of these or not.

Comment: Thank you. Will run same queries on same data different times of the day.

Comment: Is there a way to provision multiple access keys to access athena? Users shouldn’t be able to see each others data. And also it uses same s3 directory to write query results, the users would be able to access the queries made by other users. Is there any way to restrict other users who use same s3 bucket for query results?

Comment: You can provision multiple access keys, yes. Each user should have their own IAM user or role. Each IAM user or role should have permissions only to the data on S3 that they are allowed to access. How to set this up is much too complicated to explain in a short comment, unfortunately. You can ensure that people can't access each others results by making sure they don't have list access in the results bucket. The result files have unguessable names. If I answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer, and perhaps upvote it.

Comment: Appreciate your response. And how does athena process queries in background? Will it use single instance for an account and serve multiple tenants? Or will it process on multiple instances?(scaling up and down based on query requests?)